# Export layer as a file in Adobe Fireworks

Tags: adobe-fireworks

I'm trying to export a layer in fireworks to an image file. When I go to file>export and select layer, it exports everything to one file (no different from saving a fireworks image).

How do I accomplish this easily?

What I'm doing now is create a new image, copy the layer and save it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`File` → `Export…`

Choose `Layers to Files` from the dropdown. Under the `Options…` you can choose the target file type (or you can choose to use the document's optimization settings set in the `Optimize` window).

Then Fireworks exports the layers (all visible) as separate files. (If you want just one layer, you can hide the others.)

Also note that Fireworks' **layers** are represented as **folders** in the `Layers` window, unlike in f.ex. Photoshop.

Comment: what if I want to export all of my bitmap "layers", not "folders"? Can I convert a "bitmap" to a "folder layer"?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the need - this extension does the magic:
http://johndunning.com/fireworks/about/ExportSelection

You select the object(s), or layer(s), and choose ***Commands > Export > Export Selection - Background Transparent***. There are more options, but this is the common and best one. It will export a SINGLE image with the layers you picked on alpha transparency.