# Fireworks: Export from layers - Include common layer?

Tags: tools, adobe-fireworks, export

I am versed in [exporting all visible layers in Fireworks to separate files](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1027/export-layer-as-a-file-in-adobe-fireworks). What I would like to is one notch more sophisticated - I'd like to include one or more of these layers in each and every exported layer.

For example, if I had layers like this:

```
 - Smiley Face
 - Sad Face
 - Shocked Face
 - ...
 - Purple Gradient (<-- common background layer)
```

I'd like to end up with a set of files that is named for each layer except "Purple Gradient", and I'd like the purple gradient to be visible behind each exported layer.

Comment: As I'm typing this I'm thinking Fireworks "States" are probably the way to do this - been a while since I touched that feature set.

Comment: Sure enough, `states` work fine for this sort of thing.  I'd still be curious if there were a simpler way to do this - `states` adds another layer of configuration to do.